# cast api get device ip address

Tags: google-chrome, casting, google-cast

Working on a project that casts videos from a chrome app to chrome-cast, I'm unable to decide what's the best way to decide which network adapter ip address i should pass to the chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo api method (I have multiple  addresses that starts with 192.168...)

I am able to list all adapters using: chrome.system.network.getNetworkInterfaces.

And also able to find the device using this method, but it is not very stable and doesn't list the device everytime I try it:

```
chrome.mdns.onServiceList.addListener(function (e)
{
    console.log('mdns.onServiceList', e);
},
{
    'serviceType': '_googlecast._tcp.local'
});
```

I thought maybe there's an options to get the ip of the device the user selected using the cast extension but couldn't find any.

so, what is the best way to decide which network adaptar/address is the one accessible to the chrome-cast device.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe someone knows, is there a way to get ip the receiver ip address from the cast extension directly?

Comment: Why do you need to know the ip address of your cast device?

Comment: because I want to serve a video from the user's machine (and not from the internet or a server with a fixed IP address). 
In my chrome (packaged) app, i'm able to get the PC's network interfaces (using chrome.system.network.getNetworkInterfaces) but i'm enable to decide which network address is visible to the selected cast device.

Comment: I have to think about it but I doubt that is exposed through any of the APIs. One thing that comes to mind is the following: if on your receiver side you can get its local/LAN ip address, you can send a message back to your sender with that info.

Comment: yeah, but that mean i will have to write a custom receiver... 
the extension itself is able to send the user's desktop screen which means that it does know the right ip address to use...
Another option I thought about was to use the new JS Presentation API, but it doesn't seems to work... (thanks for your time Ali :) )

Comment: Maybe it is possible to get from the extension the local IP that is used to communicate with the cast device instead the device's IP? - that would be awesome!!